# How to use elasticsearch server instead of installing local machine

Tags: elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am learning `Elasticsearch` to implement it in my `Django` Project. When I installed and ran the server on my computer, it became very slow and sometimes my pc is became hung.

I am trying to find an alternative solution to use elastic search server, is there any remote elastic server to use? can anyone suggest me any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some company has an Elasticsearch cluster platform (as service).

for example:

https://bonsai.io/

I think It is free for start.